# Background color scheme for distinguishing between environments (Sandbox vs Production)

Tags: sandbox, production, chrome

Can we brand Staging environment(Sandbox) differently than production environment because it was causing confusion with the end users not knowing which they were logging into. With more users moving over, this continues to be a problem.

I know we can use [Salesforce Colored Favicon chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-colored-favico/peohlnebahcddpmfaplmilpkgbkkcdho).Do we have any other options other than installing chrome extension ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have added below html code to home page component

```
    <style>
body.sfdcBody{background-color:green;background-image:none;}
.multiforce{background-color:green;background-image:none;}
.bPageHeader .phHeader TD.searchCell{background-color:green;background-image:none;}
.bPageHeader TD.vtop:right{background-color:green;background-image:none;}
</style>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice - Always the innovator!

Comment: Great idea - like it

Comment: Tried it, its not working.. donno what wrong am doing.

Comment: Got it working by checking in Messages & Alerts present in Home Page Layouts

Comment: This works great on the data pages. Is there a way to also change this color on the setup pages?

Comment: sadly, as of Winter 16 http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_home_page_comp_changes.htm , this no longer works

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few more options

1. You can brand Salesforce1 to be different colors and show a different image on loading between environments:
   [image]
2. You can brand the Console to be different between environments.
3. You can change your logo to be different between environments:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

The already there solution to this is to train your end users to always look in the top right hand corner for the black box that will tell them they are in a sandbox and which sandbox:

[image: sandbox indicator]

I know this requires attention to detail that is not always present but if you remind people often enough the idea may stick...

Comment: I agree. If you change color scheme you will have the same issue. People will say the color is not enough, they get to used to processes and not detail. Train, train, reenforce, train.

Comment: Before Salesforce took away our sidebar hacks, we could have done something. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

Ah @sherod has just released a chrome extension that will do this. I can't find the link to it at the moment because searching for chrome extensions on mobile is almost impossible, but here is his tweet about it https://twitter.com/sherod/status/618730817762652160

Comment: This is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ive-a-feeling-were-not-in/kagabgbcemdhfgefjnnpfnhfpednebbk?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I always change the logo in the upper left to have our company logo, then the environment name in large unmissable red letters.

- Setup > Create > Apps...
- Click "Edit" next to your app
- Look for "Choose the Image Source for the Custom App Logo"